# JEE 7.0 JPA 2.1 Payara 4.1.x Eclipselink persistence.xml

Tags: java-ee-7, persistence.xml, jpa-2.1

I have to migrate old jee 6/jpa2.0 project to jee 7/jpa2.1.
I migrated in pom.xml like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>payara-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.154</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I still use ojdbc6 because of Oracle Database 11g, not yet migrated.

I replaced in persistence.xml the persistence tag and now is looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence 
    version="2.1" 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="pu1" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/OraclePool</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="INFO" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="pu2" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/OraclePoolNoTransact</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="INFO" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="true" />           
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.type" value="HARD" />
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.size" value="4000000000" /> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now eclipse say:

```
The persistence.xml file does not have supported content for this JPA platform.
```

When I compile the code with maven I receive:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project project.name: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project project.name: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:695)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:684)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:553)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:407)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataDescriptor.getProject(MetadataDescriptor.java:1152)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.<init>(ClassAccessor.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.MappedSuperclassAccessor.<init>(MappedSuperclassAccessor.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.ORMetadata.reloadMappedSuperclass(ORMetadata.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.addPotentialMappedSuperclass(ClassAccessor.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EmbeddableAccessor.discoverMappedSuperclassesAndInheritanceParents(EmbeddableAccessor.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EmbeddableAccessor.preProcess(EmbeddableAccessor.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.addPotentialEmbeddableAccessor(ClassAccessor.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.addAccessor(ClassAccessor.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.addAccessorFields(ClassAccessor.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.addAccessors(ClassAccessor.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.preProcessForCanonicalModel(ClassAccessor.java:1238)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.objects.PersistenceUnit.preProcessForCanonicalModel(PersistenceUnit.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:400)
    ... 35 more
```

I did a search on web but no idea why is this happened.
Anyone have any idea?

Best Regards,
Mihai

Comment: The error about persistence.xml was from the settings of project facets.

Comment: But the compiling error with maven install is still there.

Comment: what did you change in your project facets to resolve it? I am  looking at the same issue.

Comment: Posted that comment too quickly. It was simply that my project facet for JPA was set to 1.0. Changing it to the correct version was all that was required.

Answer (score 2):

As you will be using Java EE 7 API which is provided by your server (Payara). Why you are adding this dependency :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The default JPA implementation shipped in Glassfish/Payara is EclipseLink by default. So the declared dependency have no more value to add to you, and  probably it's the main cause for the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:407)
```

Try to remove this dependency and try to build your project.